# Why are courts called "Elohim"?

Tags: hebrew, beit-din-court

There are numerous places in the Torah where the word  "Elohim" אלהים does not mean "G-d", but rather a court.

Why are courts named after one of G-d's names, and considering that G-d has many names, why was this one specifically chosen?

Comment: Maybe God was named after the court? Why do you think the court is named after God?

Comment: Please provide a source where these "numerous places" where the Torah refers to courts. As far as I know there's only 1 place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *elohim* means power which is also why idols are called *elohim acheirim*. Pagans regard their *gods* as beings which manifest various powers, somewhat like comic book characters (like the X-Men). They regard the concept of Hashem as *too lofty* to be connected to human beings and therefore worship the *powers* that have direct control or connection with the physical universe (see the Chabad citation at the end of this post).

In the case of the courts, they are a group of people who have been given the *power* by Hashem to enforce the rules of the Torah. Thus, their connection to Hashem gives them the name *powers*.

[Elokim](https://ohr.edu/4514)

> This name of G-d is based on the Hebrew word “el” which means simply
>   “power” or “strength”. An example of this usage is in the description
>   of Lavan’s pursuing and confronting Jacob during his return to the
>   Land of Israel. Lavan says, “Yesh b’el yadi [sic] - It is in my power to do
>   you harm, but the G-d of your father addressed me last night [in a
>   dream] saying, ‘Beware of speaking with Jacob either bad or good’”
>   (Gen 31:29). Rashi and Onkelus both explain “el” to mean power or
>   strength.
>
> The name “Elokim”, then, in reference to G-d, connotes His complete
>   mastership and control over everything.
>
> A third usage of this term refers to judges. For example, if on
>   account of poverty or theft a Jewish man was indentured to work for a
>   Jewish master, then chose to stay in servitude despite being given the
>   opportunity to be released, he was to be brought before the “elohim” –
>   judges – who would order that the man’s ear be pierced symbolically
>   stating, “G-d says the Children of Israel are My servants; and this
>   one chooses to be a servant of a servant!” (Ex. 21:6).
>
> However, regarding this last usage, the commentaries suggest a
>   relationship with “Elokim”. Namely, the Torah court of judges is
>   called by the word for G-d since it carries out G-d’s laws on earth
>   (Ibn Ezra). Alternatively, because G-d’s Presence and influence rests
>   upon the judges (Ramban). This is based on the Sages’ explanation of
>   the verse “in the midst of judges (elohim) G-d will judge” (Psalms
>   82:1).

[Why is G‑d Called "Elokim"?](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/638043/jewish/Why-is-Gd-Called-Elokim.htm)

> They knew of this concept of Havaya, but they considered it far too
>   lofty an idea, seemingly inaccessible and irrelevant to their lives.
>   Instead, they connected to the many forces of nature. They called
>   these "Elohim"—meaning, "mighty forces."
>
> That's why, as the Biblical commentator Baal HaTurim points out, the
>   Hebrew letters in the name Elohim have the same gematria (numerical
>   value) as "haTeva"—which means the natural order.